# Is there a need of seperate Key Schema(other than a schema for fields) while writing Avro producer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, schema, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am writing Java Avro Producer code for my project. I have registered an Avro schema for all the fields which need to be passed.

My Registered Schema-

{

"name": "Claim",

"type": "record",

"namespace": "com.schema.avro",

"fields": [

```
{

  "name": "icn",

  "type": "string"

},

{

  "name": "fln,

  "type": "int"

},
```

]

}

I am using "icn" field value as a key but I don't have a key schema registered separately. I am not sure if that is required.

i) Can I directly use a field already in my current schema("icn" in this case) as the key without having to register a key schema?

ii) Do I need to register the key schema separately? If so, is that part of the schema already created for fields or is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not required to use avro for keys. If your key is of type string you may use *org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer*. If you want to use avro, you need to register the schema for each object type.

Comment: Thanks Katya. I was able to use a key of string type with StringSerializer.